# google compute engine tool gcloud is exceptionally slow

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, att, gcloud

I tried downloading and using the gcloud bash tool to manage my accounts, however everything I do with the tool is exceptionally slow. It will take MINUTES to reply to a command that is typed.

Is there perhaps a firewall I need to open up on my router or something else to get this to work fast like it's supposed to? For example, the "Installing..." lines in this video https://youtu.be/4y4-xn4Vi04?t=1m21s -- you'll notice they are all complete in the tutorial within a few seconds. This takes over 10 minutes to complete on my machine.

I'm on a newer Macbook Air, and all other internet/etc works really fast. I'm on a decent speed internet connection from AT&T Uverse (30mbps/3mbps). All other browsing is fast and just fine, the only thing in the world I have a problem with is this gcloud tool.

Comment: Are others facing the same issue? I am facing this in on Mac OS X El Captain and cant seem to find a clear solution. Running `traceroute www.googleapis.com` reveals the delay on remote Google servers and not at the client or router's end. gcloud version is SDK 169.0.0

Comment: using gcloud on an f1-micro instance is slower than actually starting the whole instance.
I really hope Google is going to exchange this extremely bulky tool against something FAST

Comment: I'm getting this recently (on Linux), and using strace have seen that it's when refreshing auth tokens with `gcloud.py config config-helper` - both with the `gcloud` & `kubectl` commands - it appears to be hanging during a DNS lookup of `metadata.google.internal` for me. Using Google's public DNS servers may help.

Comment: @AndrewRembrandt Had the exact same behaviour (on an M1 Mac), and traced it back to this same DNS lookup that was hanging. Your solution of adding google's public DNS as a secondary DNS server to my laptop fixed the issue !

Comment: This is still an issue in 2023 for any devs that see this...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I traced this back to packet filters. When I deleted this rule #5 in my AT&T Uverse modem/router (Motorola NVG589), everything works ok. This was a default setting in the modem which caused all sorts of issues.

[image: packet filters]

Comment: this answer helped me tremendously.. ipv6 was enabled, had to login to the arris router admin and under firewall, disable `block fragmented ip packets` (enabled by default..)

Comment: This help me as well on AT&T Small Business fiber. In fact none of the rules were enabled for us, but I still had this problem. Disabling the packet filter completely solved it.

Comment: Thank you.  I have their fiber service as well.  I had to disable all the packet filters as well then reset my broadband connection.

Answer (score 20):

I just ran into a similar issue myself, though not as bad as minute long response times. What helped me was turning off the usage reporting.

Looking at some timings:

```
$ gcloud config set disable_usage_reporting False
$ time gcloud compute -h | tail -1
  real  0m7.058s
  user  0m0.464s
  sys   0m0.088s
```

A whopping 7 secs to access the help!

Fortunately, this improves greatly after disabling reporting:

```
$ gcloud config set disable_usage_reporting True
$ time gcloud compute -h | tail -1
  real  0m0.541s
  user  0m0.459s
  sys   0m0.080s
```

Much better!

Comment: What version of the SDK are you currently using?

Comment: gcloud -v returns: "Google Cloud SDK 0.9.58"

Comment: This answer still applies on Google Cloud SDK 137.0.0!

Comment: This is still an issue on Google Cloud SDK version 139.0.1 and Mac OS X Sierra. I think it's a different issue from the one noticed by Mark Shust. Commands went from taking about 10 seconds each to taking less than a second.

Comment: On windows 10, gcloud ssh into docker-optimized image, not as slow as reported about, but still extremely distracting. Disabling reporting helps only marginally.

Comment: Looks like subsequent runs of the above command (without updating the config) reduces the time anyways (maybe some kind of caching). This what I got on two subsequent runs without any change in the config:
First run: 
`time gcloud compute -h | tail -1
real 0m3.031s
user 0m0.756s
sys 0m0.477s`

Second run:
`time gcloud compute -h | tail -1
real 0m0.585s
user 0m0.426s
sys 0m0.147s`

Also I didn't see any visible difference by disabling reporting on ver SDK 169.0.0

Comment: Still pretty slow with v310.0.0. 1.8 sec just for `gcloud -v` or `gcloud config get-value product` on my machine.

Answer (score 3):

Mark Shust's answer hinted to me that something might be going on with IPv6. Turning this support off in my router brought the gcloud times back to a couple of seconds from over 2 minutes for a `gcloud compute machine-types list`.

Note: I've also had to turn off IPv6 support in apt for a similar reason so this is likely a problem with my router or ISP, not the google cloud sdk.

Comment: I just disabled ipv6 on my router and it worked as well

Comment: In addition to my comment on the OP, it turns out my real issue was actually to do with the fact that IPv6 was mis-configured on a second router in my home network (it was requesting prefix delegation when it shouldn't have). As soon as I corrected the prefix issue, the gcloud sdk delays (when renewing auth tokens I suspect) went away.
NB: Running `strace -f -e trace=network -s 10000 gcloud <args>` shows some interesting things that one would normally not expect - it appears that google has written it to detect if it's running within google's internal networks, which can be problematic

Comment: This also was an issue with my network; misconfigured ipv6; I disabled ipv6 from the adapter settings in windows. In my case gcloud was hanging forever, not just slow.

Answer (score 0):

Same behavior for me.
Simple command hang on

```
gcloud compute instances list --log-http --verbosity debug
```

DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): oauth2.googleapis.com:443

If   I `ping oauth2.googleapis.com PING oauth2.googleapis.com(sof02s34-in-x0a.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4017:80b::200a)) 56 data bytes`   you can see IPv6.
In my case I have router Zyxel EX3301-T0

Disable `LAN IPv6 Mode Setup` and
`ping oauth2.googleapis.com PING oauth2.googleapis.com (172.217.17.138) 56(84) bytes of data. 64 bytes from 172.217.17.138 (172.217.17.138): icmp_seq=1 ttl=114 time=82.8 ms`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I using WSl, however my local computer using window already install gcloud cli and it making it so slow when using on WSL. So I resolve it by install again the gcloud cli on my WSL ubuntu follow the document.
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install#deb