# Nodejs/Gcloud/kubectl any command we run from WSL2 is deadly slow

Tags: node.js, windows-subsystem-for-linux, kubectl, wsl-2

I referred many solutions yet no luck. I have a linux automation which runs few gcloud commands with some conditions. I made this script with node js, but it is incredibly slow that I even finish it manually before the scrips completes the run.

Same with the gcloud commands when I connect to a cluster and kubectl commands when i query something.

Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

It could be a DNS config error on WSL side. I hadthe same issue today, here's how I fixed it !

#### 1. Checking the (deadly slow) response time

```
[tbg@~] time kubectl get deployments

No resources found in default namespace.

real    0m1.212s
user    0m0.151s
sys     0m0.050s
```

#### 2. Checking the WSL/DNS configuration

```
[tbg@~]  cat /etc/wsl.conf

[network]
generateResolvConf=false
```

```
[tbg@~]  cat /etc/resolv.conf

nameserver XX.XXX.XXX.X
nameserver YYY.YY.YY.YY
nameserver 1.1.1.1
```

**If you see that, remove these lines to get back to automatic resolv.conf generation and restart WSL (wsl --shutdown)**

#### 3. Checking the (**fixed !**) response time

```
[tbg@~] time kubectl get deployments

No resources found in default namespace.

real    0m10.530s
user    0m0.087s
sys     0m0.043s
```

I found out my resolv.conf configuration was causing that latency, by trying to reinstall kubectl with apt, and finding apt really slow too

Answer (score -1):

Right now access to /mnt folders in WSL2 is [too slow](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4197) and by default at launch the entire Windows PATH is added to the Linux $PATH so any Linux binary that scans $PATH will make things [unbearably slow.](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5159)

To disable this feature, edit the **/etc/wsl.conf** to add the following section:

```
[interop]

appendWindowsPath = false
```

Avoid adding Windows Path to Linux $PATH and best for now is adding folders to the $PATH manually.
Terminate the WSL distro (wsl.exe --terminate <distro_name>) to make it immediately effective or  `wsl.exe --shutdown` and start the [terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4498#issuecomment-629133830) again.

Refer to the [stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61953082/why-is-my-gcloud-command-suddenly-very-slow-inside-wsl2) for more [information.](https://cymbeline.ch/2018/04/10/fix-slow-kubectl-on-windows/)

Comment: I did try this already. I think I am missing this part "Avoid adding Windows Path to Linux $PATH and best for now is adding folders to the $PATH manually"

What should we copy? Pls explain

Comment: Tried it, changed nothing. My PATH doesn't include any Windows element tho